# Android: Starting ActionMode inside ViewPager's Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-actionmode

I am working on an app where I have a viewpager with 3 fragments in it using  Tablayout. Now I am trying to start the actionmode for Recycler view to select multiple views on LongClick. Below is the code

```
actionMode = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallback);
```

but it always give me this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v7.view.ActionMode android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.startSupportActionMode(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode$Callback)' on a null object reference
```

I have also tried it like this

```
MyMainActivity activity=(MyMainActivity)getActiivty();
activity.startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallback);
```

But it gaves me the same error. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your ActionMode.Callbacks:

```
ActionMode.Callback actionModeCallbacks = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }
        ///
    };
```

Change the boolean from false to true:

```
ActionMode.Callback actionModeCallbacks = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return true;
        }
        ///
    };
```

Comment: it's not fix the crash :/